# Transformar comando Sql em LAMBDA

Tags: c#, sql, expressões-lambda

Estou aprendendo um pouco sobre LAMBDA e tentei converter essa query em LAMBDA, porém travei.

Tenho 2 classes:

```
public class Voo {
    public string idVoo {get;set;}
    public DateTime dtVoo {get;set;}
    public string dsHoraInicial {get;set}
    public DateTime dtVooFim {get;set;}
    public string dsHoraFinal {get;set}
    public int idAeronave {get;set;}
    public virtual Aeronave Aeronave {get;set;}
}

public class Aeronave {
   public int idAeronave {get;set;}
   public string dsAeronave {get;set;}
   public string cdAeronave {get;set;} 
   public virtual ICollection<Voo> Voos {get;set;}
}
```

O usuário deve informar um determinado período com 2 datas como entrada e a query faria uma agrupamento das cdAeronaves (código das aeronaves) e as horas de voo totais efetuadas por aeronaves com aquele código.

```
Aeronave       Horas de Voo
----------------------
PR-QQ              0,7

PR-UU              2,9
```

Abaixo segue a procedure que tenho que utilizar para adaptar no LAMBDA.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE 
    @dtInicial DATETIME,
    @dtFinal DATETIME
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT a.cdAeronave 'dsAeronave', a.idAeronave
        ,SUM(CONVERT(numeric(10,1),DATEDIFF(minute,Convert(DATETIME, v.dtVoo+v.dsHoraInicial), Convert(DATETIME, v.dtVooFim+v.dsHoraFinal))/60.2)) AS 'HDV'
    FROM Voo v
    JOIN Aeronave a ON a.idAeronave = v.idAeronave
    WHERE v.dtVoo BETWEEN @dtInicial AND @dtFinal
    GROUP BY a.cdAeronave, a.idAeronave
END
```

E abaixo a tentativa do LAMBDA.

```
IQueryable<Voo> selecionar = hdva.Include(a => a.Aeronave)
                     .Where(v => v.dtVoo <= Convert.ToDateTime(v.dtVoo + v.dsHoraInicial))
                     .Where(v => v.dtVoo >= Convert.ToDateTime(v.dtVooFim + v.dsHoraFinal))                         
                     .Select(s => new
                            {
                                idAeronave = s.Aeronave.idAeronave,
                                dsAeronave = s.Aeronave.cdAeronave,

                                hdv = Sum(Convert.ToDecimal
                                                            (
                                                                 DbFunctions.DiffMinutes
                                                                                (
                                                                                Convert.ToDateTime(q.dtVoo + q.dsHoraInicial),
                                                                                Convert.ToDateTime(q.dtVooFim + q.dsHoraFinal)
                                                                                ) / 60
                                                            )
                                            )
                            })
                    .GroupBy(a => a.Aeronave.cdAeronave, a => a.Aeronave.idAeronave.ToString());
```

Sei que o SUM está errado e que o '`q'(The name q does not exist in the current context)` dentro do SUM não está sendo chamado, mas não estou sabendo como fazer tudo isso funcionar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partindo do princípio que temos esta informação de amostragem:

```
List<Aeronave> aeronaves = new List<Aeronave>()
{
    new Aeronave()
    {
        cdAeronave = "001",
        dsAeronave = "001",
        idAeronave = 1
    },
    new Aeronave()
    {
        cdAeronave = "002",
        dsAeronave = "002",
        idAeronave = 2
    }
};

List<Voo> voos = new List<Voo>()
{
    new Voo()
    {
        Aeronave = aeronaves.First(r => r.idAeronave == 1),
        dsHoraInicial = "10:00",
        dsHoraFinal = "20:00",
        dtVoo = new DateTime(2019, 1, 10),
        dtVooFim = new DateTime(2019, 1, 11),
        idAeronave = 1,
        idVoo = "001"
    },
    new Voo()
    {
        Aeronave = aeronaves.First(r => r.idAeronave == 1),
        dsHoraInicial = "09:00",
        dsHoraFinal = "20:00",
        dtVoo = new DateTime(2019, 1, 9),
        dtVooFim = new DateTime(2019, 1, 9),
        idAeronave = 1,
        idVoo = "002"
    },
    new Voo()
    {
        Aeronave = aeronaves.First(r => r.idAeronave == 2),
        dsHoraInicial = "10:00",
        dsHoraFinal = "09:00",
        dtVoo = new DateTime(2019, 1, 8),
        dtVooFim = new DateTime(2019, 1, 9),
        idAeronave = 2,
        idVoo = "003"
    }
};

var aeronave = aeronaves.First(r => r.idAeronave == 1);
aeronave.Voos = voos.Where(r => r.idAeronave == 1).ToList();

aeronave = aeronaves.First(r => r.idAeronave == 2);
aeronave.Voos = voos.Where(r => r.idAeronave == 2).ToList();
```

Temos então:

> - `idAeronave = 1` => 34h (`idVoo 001`) + 11h (`idVoo 002`) * 60 = 2.700m / 60,2 = **44,9 HDV**
> - `idAeronave = 2` => 23h (`idVoo 003`) * 60 = 1.380m / 60,2 = **22,9 HDV**

Com o código abaixo, em ***Query Expression***, temos exatamente esse resultado (contabilizando todas as datas, desde `01/01/1900` à data atual, `27/02/2019`):

```
DateTime dataInicial = DateTime.MinValue;
DateTime dataFinal = DateTime.Now;

var lista = from voo in voos
            join anave in aeronaves on voo.idAeronave equals anave.idAeronave into voonaves
            from anave in voonaves.DefaultIfEmpty()
            where voo.dtVoo >= dataInicial && voo.dtVoo <= dataFinal
            group anave by new { anave.cdAeronave, anave.idAeronave } into gnaves
            select new
            {
                dsAeronave = gnaves.Key.cdAeronave,
                idAeronave = gnaves.Key.idAeronave,
                HDV = gnaves.Max(r => r.Voos.Sum(x => Math.Round(DateTime.Parse(string.Format(@"{0} {1}", x.dtVooFim.ToShortDateString(), x.dsHoraFinal))
                    .Subtract(DateTime.Parse(string.Format(@"{0} {1}", x.dtVoo.ToShortDateString(), x.dsHoraInicial))).TotalMinutes / 60.2, 1)))
            };
```

Resultados:

> [0] = { dsAeronave = "001", idAeronave = 1, HDV = **44.9** }
>   [1] = { dsAeronave = "002", idAeronave = 2, HDV = **22.9** }

Uma outra perspetiva, ***Lambda Expression***, com os mesmos resultados:

```
DateTime dataInicial = DateTime.MinValue;
DateTime dataFinal = DateTime.Now;

var lista2 = aeronaves.GroupBy(r => new { r.cdAeronave, r.idAeronave })
            .Select(r => new
            {
                dsAeronave = r.Key.cdAeronave,
                idAeronave = r.Key.idAeronave,
                HDV = r.Max(x => x.Voos.Sum(y => Math.Round(DateTime.Parse(string.Format(@"{0} {1}", y.dtVooFim.ToShortDateString(), y.dsHoraFinal))
                    .Subtract(DateTime.Parse(string.Format(@"{0} {1}", y.dtVoo.ToShortDateString(), y.dsHoraInicial))).TotalMinutes / 60.2, 1)))
            });
```

Comment: Joao, de fato, testei e ainda tive problemas com o sum, mas muito obrigado pelo help!

Comment: Se a resposta lhe foi útil, dê um UP! Mas já agora, que erro lhe dá?

Comment: Desculpe. O erro diz que Sum não é um método de Voos já que pertence a classe Voo. Só funcionaria caso fosse um IEnumerable, onde este método poderia ser invocado. Outro erro é o Unexpected character $.

Comment: Resposta alterada para evitar erros. Tente executar da forma como está agora.

Comment: Fiz as consultas de voos e aeronaves assim `ICollection<Voo> voos = db.Voos.ToList();
ICollection<Aeronave> aeronaves = db.Aeronaves.ToList();` Modifiquei o `where` para isso `voo.dtVoo >= DateTime.Parse(string.Format(@"{0} {1}", viewModel.dtVoo.ToShortDateString(), voo.dsHoraInicial))
                            && viewModel.dtVoo <= DateTime.Parse(string.Format(@"{0} {1}", viewModel.dtVooFim.ToShortDateString(),voo.dsHoraFinal))`

Porém o `lista` não funciona quando eu coloco ele no `foreach` após um bom tempo esperando.

Comment: @RodrigoFerraz, alterei consideravelmente a minha resposta e incluí exemplos. Espero que ajude!

Comment: Martins, esse código retornou todas as aeronaves, mesmo aquelas sem Voo, em qualquer intervalo de tempo informado, pois ficou faltando o where. Irei tentar implementar essa parte, mas muito obrigado!

Comment: Só poderia explicar, por favor, por que incluiu o MAX?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90342/discussion-between-joao-martins-and-rodrigo-ferraz).